# Which algorithm does NLTK Decision Tree Classifier use

Tags: python, nltk

I want to know which algorithm the NLTK Decision Tree Classifier uses (i.e. ID3, C4.5, ..), but couldn't find the information in the official documentation. Is there any source on this topic?

Comment: Take a look at the source code: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/decisiontree.py